# Where can you find Swords Secret online?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, fighter, archetype

I was reading the [Lore Warden (PRG:AG)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo-fighter-archetypes/lore-warden-fighter-archetype) archetype (careful, there is another Lore Warden archetype for fighter) and one of its features is the [swords secret](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Fighter/archetypes/paizo-fighter-archetypes/lore-warden-fighter-archetype/#Swords_Secret_Ex), but I cant find any of them online.

Swords Secret

> A lore warden learns specialized techniques that help her to quickly analyze and defeat her foes. At 3rd level, a lore warden gains one swords secret, and she gains an additional swords secret for every 4 fighter levels gained after 3rd. Except where noted, a lore warden cannot select the same swords secret more than once.

I wasnt able to find this listed on d20pfsrd, nythys, or with a google search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### They're listed on Archives of Nethys

On AoN, [Lore Warden](https://www.aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Fighter%20Lore%20Warden) states:

> **Swords Secret (Ex)**: A lore warden learns specialized techniques that help her to quickly analyze and defeat her foes. At 3rd level, a lore warden gains one swords secret, and she gains an additional swords secret for every 4 fighter levels gained after 3rd. Except where noted, a lore warden cannot select the same swords secret more than once.
>
> *Exploit Weakness (Ex)*: The lore warden adds one-third her class level on attack rolls to confirm critical hits. At 11th level, whenever she confirms a critical hit, her weapon attacks ignore the first 5 points of damage reduction or hardness the target has until the end of her next turn. At 19th level, the lore warden can automatically confirm a critical hit once per round when she threatens a critical hit.
>
> *Hair’s Breadth (Ex)*: Once per day when subject to a critical hit, the lore warden can attempt an Acrobatics check to reduce the damage as an immediate action. If the result of this Acrobatics check is greater than the opponent’s confirmation roll, she negates the critical hit; the attack still hits and deals normal damage. The lore warden must be at least 11th level to select this swords secret. At 15th level she can use this secret one additional time per day.
>
> *Know Thy Enemy (Ex)*: When the lore warden succeeds at a Knowledge check to identify a creature’s abilities and weaknesses, she can also use a standard action to grant herself a +2 insight bonus on all attack and weapon damage rolls made against that enemy. This bonus lasts for a number of rounds equal to half her class level (minimum 2 rounds), or until the lore warden uses this ability against a different creature. At 11th level, she also gains a +2 bonus to her AC against the creature when using this ability. At 19th level, the insight bonus increases to +3.
>
> *Maneuver Training (Ex)*: The lore warden gains a brawler’s maneuver training class feature, treating her fighter level as her brawler level.
>
> *Swift Assessment (Ex)*: The lore warden can now use her know thy enemy swords secret as a move action. At 15th level, she can use this ability as a swift action. She must have the know thy enemy swords secret before choosing this swords secret.
>
> This replaces armor training and armor mastery.

Each of the italicized items is a sword secret they can learn. On D20PFSRD, due to poor formatting, they appear as individual class features.

Comment: I completely took them as additional abilities and had not read them that closely because they weren't defined as swords secrets clearly. Thank you